# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

At first there was no error, but when i run it again theres a unkown error and I cannot fix it. does anyone know how to fix this problem?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and errors as plain text, with correct formatting. This is unreadable.

Comment: IMHO you have an error in your `/res` folders, Maybe you have duplicate files in e.g. the `main` and `debug` branches of the code. Posting the folder structure for your project should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    aaptOptions {
       cruncherEnabled = false
   }
   dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   }
```